# (psycopg2.errors.UndefinedFunction) function str(numeric) does not exist

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to search in numeric field by substring

```
SELECT currency_value FROM invoice WHERE STR(currency_value) ILIKE '100';
```

And i get

```
 function str(numeric) does not exist
```

What is the correct way to cast numeric to string in PostgreSQL ?

Comment: I'd consider the CAST() function, i.e. `cast(currency_value as varchar(11))`.

Comment: Where [in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions.html) did you find the `str()` function?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, "In what manual did you find..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ILIKE expression needs a `%` for wildcarding, btw. Unclear if you meant to omit that. There's two ways to do casts, `CAST(x AS type)` and `x::type`. The string type in postgres is `text`.

```
// Will match "100.23"
SELECT currency_value FROM invoice WHERE CAST(currency_value as text) ILIKE '100%';
// Will match "32100"
SELECT currency_value FROM invoice WHERE currency_value::text ILIKE '%100';
```